# Как открыть документ не прописывая полный путь?

Tags: delphi-7

Документ лежит в одной папке с проектом. Прописала:

```
ShellExecute(Handle,'open',PChar('D:\2016-2017\äèïëîìíàÿ ðàáîòà\1.pdf'),nil,nil,SW_SHOWDEFAULT); -

WinExec('D:\2016-2017\äèïëîìíàÿ ðàáîòà\1.pdf'',1);
```

тут нужно полный путь вводить

Comment: Кракозябры в пути к файлу вас не смущают?

Answer (score 0):

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + '1.pdf'), nil, nil, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

`ParamStr(0)` - содержит полный путь к исполняемому файлу

`ExtractFilePath` - соответственно, убирает из строки имя файла, оставляя только путь.

Answer (score -1):

В вашем случае

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar('1.pdf'), nil, nil, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Comment: спасибо! Я пробовала так, но почему то не открывает.